# How to control the spacing/indentation of an HTML container tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a bootstrap navbar and I have put the contents of the navbar inside a container.  With the container, the indentation (for lack of a better term) of the navbar is a little too wide for my liking. Is there a way to shorten the indentation and bring the content of the navbar closer to the edges of the browser (by way of HTML or CSS)?

Seeing the code may not be useful but here it is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `.container-fluid` and not `.container`. From the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers):

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
          <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

PS: You probably don't need a `.container` div. Just tried without it here:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
        <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, I looks like container-fluid does leave a small indentation which is what I was looking for, versus when I take it out completely it removes the spacing entirely and practically spans the entire width. Small and subtle difference between the two but it does what I was looking for

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark the answer as accepted for anybody who would like to solve a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using css media query you can adjust the bootstrap default container width. I just adjusted the max container width by adding `small` class. You can adjust your `max-width` based on your requirement.

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.small.container {
    max-width: 980px; //overwritten the default boostrap width
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.small.container {
    max-width: 960px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.small.container {
    max-width: 720px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px)
.small.container {
    max-width: 540px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="small container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input aria-label="Search" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" type="search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```